# Set TimeToLive for Azure Queue messages in Node.js

Tags: node.js, azure, azure-storage-queues

How can I set the TTL for messages I put in the Azure queue, such that they don't last beyond 30 seconds using Node.js?

I can't seem to find any mention of Time To Live in the SDK for Node.js on Github.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at the documentation for `createMessage` on Github (https://github.com/WindowsAzure/azure-sdk-for-node/blob/master/lib/services/queue/queueservice.js), you'll notice that you can provide additional parameters to that operation. One of the parameter is **`messagettl`**. You would need to specify that parameter. See sample code below. Here the message will automatically expire after 30 seconds.

```
var azure = require('azure');
var queueService = azure.createQueueService("account", "key");
queueService.createQueueIfNotExists("dummy", function(error){
    if(!error){
        queueService.createMessage("dummy", "Hello world!", {messagettl: 30}, function(error){
    if(!error){
        console.log("Message Created");
    }
});
    }
});
```